# How do you get the current solution directory from a VSPackage?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, solution, vs-extensibility, vspackage

Following is how you would get the current solution directory from an add-in:

```
_applicationObject = (DTE2)application;  // retrieved from OnConnection method
string solutionDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(_applicationObject.Solution.FullName);
```

How would you do this via a VSPackage?

I'm migrating a visual studio add-in to a VSPackage as I'm intending to add some user controls that require a deeper integration with the IDE.

I found some good references on the relative merits of add-ins vs integration packages such as:
http://nayyeri.net/visual-studio-addin-vs-integration-package-part-1

And some good tutorials on msdn on VSPackages such as:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138589.aspx

I haven't found a good reference yet (on msdn or otherwise) on how the higher level interfaces in add-ins (such as DTE) map to lower level interfaces in VSPackages.

Any good references out there to help with general mapping from add-in interfaces to VSPackage interfaces?

Comment: 2+ Question and answer are relevant to my interests.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found the answer to the specific question.  The VisualStudio.DTE object can be retrieved via the `GetService()` method as follows:

```
// Get an instance of the currently running Visual Studio IDE
DTE dte = (DTE)GetService(typeof(DTE));
string solutionDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dte.Solution.FullName);
```

Comment: Does this code have any issues when multiple copies of visual studio are running?

Comment: I have used with with multiple instances of VS in standard and hibernate mode and haven't run into any problems with getting the correct current solution. Earlier approaches I tried DID have trouble getting the correct instance, such as:

DTE dte = (DTE)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE"); string solutionDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dte.Solution.FullName);

Answer (score 10):

You can get a DTE object from one of these functions:

```
public static DTE GetCurrentDTE(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    /*ENVDTE. */DTE vs = (DTE)provider.GetService(typeof(DTE));
        if (vs == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("DTE not found.");
    return vs;
}

public static DTE GetCurrentDTE()
{
    return GetCurrentDTE(/* Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell. */ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider);
}
```

After that, you can get active `Solution` from `DTE.Solution` and  `Solution` path from `DTE.Solution.Path` property.

Comment: Nice code.  Now I know how to get he DTE Object.  But how do I get an IServiceProvider (When not writing a Visual Studio extension).

Answer (score 3):

If using the `IVsSolution` interface, you can use [`GetSolutionInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolution.getsolutioninfo) to obtain the path of the solution, the solution filename, and the solution user options (SUO) filename:

```
this.solution.GetSolutionInfo(
    out string solutionDirectory,
    out string solutionFile,
    out string userOptsFile);
```