# How to get the current solution name from a Visual Studio Package project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix, solution, envdte

I created a Visual Studio Package project with a custom menu I would like to add to Visual Studio (2013).

I'm trying to get the current solution name/directory in run time.

I've tried this solution:

```
DTE dte = (DTE)GetService(typeof(DTE));
string solutionDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dte.Solution.FullName);
```

but `dte.Solution.FullName` is always empty.

I though it is related to the fact that i'm running in debug mode and a new instance of Visual Studio is created for this purpose, but it happened also when I installed my extension and ran it from Visual Studio as I ran any menu.

Any ideas what i'm missing?

Thanks

P.S. the solution I used is taken from here:
[How do you get the current solution directory from a VSPackage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336818/how-do-you-get-the-current-solution-directory-from-a-vspackage)

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it by finding the `.sln` file up the directory tree from your executing assembly:

```
public static class FileUtils
{
    public static string GetAssemblyFileName() => GetAssemblyPath().Split(@"\").Last();
    public static string GetAssemblyDir() => Path.GetDirectoryName(GetAssemblyPath());
    public static string GetAssemblyPath() => Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    public static string GetSolutionFileName() => GetSolutionPath().Split(@"\").Last();
    public static string GetSolutionDir() => Directory.GetParent(GetSolutionPath()).FullName;
    public static string GetSolutionPath()
    {
        var currentDirPath = GetAssemblyDir();
        while (currentDirPath != null)
        {
            var fileInCurrentDir = Directory.GetFiles(currentDirPath).Select(f => f.Split(@"\").Last()).ToArray();
            var solutionFileName = fileInCurrentDir.SingleOrDefault(f => f.EndsWith(".sln", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (solutionFileName != null)
                return Path.Combine(currentDirPath, solutionFileName);

            currentDirPath = Directory.GetParent(currentDirPath)?.FullName;
        }

        throw new FileNotFoundException("Cannot find solution file path");
    }
}
```

Results:

```
FileUtils.GetAssemblyFileName();
"CommonLibCore.dll"
FileUtils.GetAssemblyPath();
"G:\My Files\Programming\CSharp\Projects\MyAssemblyMVC\MyAssemblyConsole\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\CommonLibCore.dll"
FileUtils.GetAssemblyDir();
"G:\My Files\Programming\CSharp\Projects\MyAssemblyMVC\MyAssemblyConsole\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1"
FileUtils.GetSolutionFileName();
"MyAssemblyMVC.sln"
FileUtils.GetSolutionPath();
"G:\My Files\Programming\CSharp\Projects\MyAssemblyMVC\MyAssemblyMVC.sln"
FileUtils.GetSolutionDir();
"G:\My Files\Programming\CSharp\Projects\MyAssemblyMVC"
```

[image]

Comment: I think this might be best solution. As i see it there might be other solutions 'hidden' for Visual Studio, thus search might fail - however if youre doing solutions inside solutions you are better of using projects anyways and have a flaw in you architecture... +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var solutionName = Path.GetFileName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
```

You need to be using *System.IO* and *System.Diagnostics*. There also might be some file extensions at the end of *solutionName* that you will need to trim.

Comment: This gives me the path to 
https://i.imgur.com/S8wddje.png
And its not what OP wanted.

Comment: This gives me "iisexpress.exe", not what's asked for.

Comment: `testhost.exe`, which is obviously not the solution name