# Get name of current solution in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I tried this:

```
String solutionName = Path.GetFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
```

but i get only the current project name.

Comment: A solution is simply a container for projects. It doesn't really mean anything in the context of a running application. If you can better explain why you need the solution name then we might be able help.

Comment: AppDomains and assemblies loaded into the AppDomain have location, like:
`Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` or `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`

Comment: "but i get only the current project name" And that´s all you should care for. In fact you can even have assemblies that don´t have any solution they "live" in, as they have been compiled by someone else who then copied those assemblies to whatever directory.

Comment: This question might already have been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336818/how-do-you-get-the-current-solution-directory-from-a-vspackage

Comment: Under what context do you call this function? If you are wring a VS addin, then you should use VS API to query the current solution, not the code snippet above.

Comment: For my project structure this worked for me:
var SolutionFullPath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName;
            var tempStrings = SolutionFullPath.Split('\\');
            var solutionName = tempStrings[2];

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current solution name from a Visual Studio Package project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699177/how-to-get-the-current-solution-name-from-a-visual-studio-package-project)